# Octeract website is not working

Tags: nonlinear-programming

I was recommended to use Octeract. I went to their website but it did not open for me.

https://octeract.com/

Am I the only one facing this problem? Where can I get the student license?

Comment: Maybe @Nikos Kazazakis (founder of octeract) can help you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the website it references is back up, so the question is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 2):

It's not just you ... and there is no need to use a forum post (which will not age well) to find out. For future reference, you might try [Down for Everyone or Just Me](https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/).